# Chrome remote debugging android: looks broken

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using `chrome://inspect/#devices` to inspect a WebView of my android-app build via cordova. It is running und an emulator on my mac. The device can be found, but if i hit "inspect" on the WebView, it opens a window like this:
[image]
The UI is really broken and i have no idea, why… It is not possible to move the blocks into the right place. If i inspect a usual webpage, the inspector looks normal.
I am using Chrome 66.0.3359.181, Canary does not work, too.
Does anyone have an idea, what is going wrong with Chrome inspecting devices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to be related to the android-version on the emulated device. Switched from Marshmallow (Android 6.0) on Nexus 7 to Oreo (Android 8.1) on Nexus 5X and inspector is working as expected…